# Trying to UTF-8 encode the Files.write(..) but getting a OutOfMemoryError

Tags: java, utf-8, out-of-memory

I'm trying to encode my text file with UTF-8. When I do this, it works.

```
protected void writeFile(Path dir, StringBuilder sb) {
    try {
        String fileName = dir.toFile().getAbsolutePath() + File.separator + getClass().getSimpleName().toLowerCase() + ".impex";
        Path path = Paths.get(fileName);
        Files.write(path, sb.toString().getBytes(), StandardOpenOption.CREATE);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

But when I use the encoding UTF-8 or UTF8 than I get a java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space. Why is that and how can I solve this issue? (My memory settings are already 2GB)

```
protected void writeFile(Path dir, StringBuilder sb) {
    try {
        String fileName = dir.toFile().getAbsolutePath() + File.separator + getClass().getSimpleName().toLowerCase() + ".impex";
        Path path = Paths.get(fileName);
        Files.write(path, sb.toString().getBytes("UTF8"), StandardOpenOption.CREATE);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: Well how large is your `StringBuilder`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looking at implemetation of getBytes, I find

```
    byte[] encode(char[] ca, int off, int len) {
        int en = scale(len, ce.maxBytesPerChar());
        byte[] ba = new byte[en];
```

that is `int en = scale(len, ce.maxBytesPerChar());` requests roughly 4 times bytes the size of String.

Do debug your code and find when exactly it gets OutOfMemory

Comment: Thanks, you were right. The OutOfMemoryException was while reading the file. (Someone first read the file, than append some Strings and saves it as a new file. Now I just append the Strings to the file, so I skip the read part).

Answer (score 2):

Use the right tool for the job. If you want to write *characters*, don’t use the method to write *bytes*.

To write the contents of a `StringBuilder sb` to a `Path path`, use

[`Files.write(path, Collections.singleton(sb), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#write(java.nio.file.Path,%20java.lang.Iterable,%20java.nio.charset.Charset,%20java.nio.file.OpenOption...))

The underlying implementation should handle partitioning of the character to byte conversion.

If it doesn’t or if you can’t live with the fact that the method appends a new line at the end of the file, you may need the following code fragment:

```
final int chunkSize=8000;
try(Writer w=Files.newBufferedWriter(path)) {
    for(int s=0, e; s<sb.length(); s=e) {
        e=Math.min(s+chunkSize, sb.length());
        w.append(sb.subSequence(s, e));
    }
}
```

Note that `Files.newBufferedWriter` defaults to `UTF-8` and that this alternative does not insert newlines between the chunks.

Answer (score 0):

UTF-8 will use multiple bytes for many Unicode characters. You prior code uses the default encoding, which generally is on Windows a limited single byte encoding.

You might try:

```
sb.trimToSize();
```

As StringBuilder on appending, always adds a bit of extra room, this might help in your case.

The following will probably have the same out-of-memory problem. It circumvents the `toString()`, so you might try it first.

```
        Files.write(path, Collections.singletonList(sb), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
```

The last attempt is to split sb:

```
        int length = sb.length();
        final int CHUNK_SIZE = 1000;
        int chunks = length / CHUNK_SIZE;
        int size = (length + CHUNK_SIZE - 1) / CHUNK_SIZE;
        List<CharSequence> chseqs = new ArrayList<>(size);
        int n = 1;
        for (int i = 0; i < length; i += n) {
            n = Math.min(CHUNK_SIZE, length - i);
            if (n == CHUNK_SIZE) {
                // Check that the last char is not the first of a surrogate pair.
                char ch = Character.charAt(chseqs, i + n - 1);
                if (Character.isHighSurrogate()) { // Leading of pair
                    --n;
                }
            }
            CharSequence chseq = sb.subSequence(i, i + n);
            chseqs.add(chseq);
        }
        Files.write(path, chseqs, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
```

A last remark, as probably most will think this: try not to use StringBuilder for such a large texts. Some Writer, or to asynchroneously couple things, a Pipe.

Comment: Java strings use UTF-16, so you have to take UTF-16 surrogates into account if you use the chunking approach.  Some Unicode codepoints use surrogates and some do not, so you do not want a given surrogate pair to straddle over a chunk boundary, where the high surrogate is in one chunk and the low surrogate is in the next chunk.  If that happens, the surrogates will be encoded to UTF-8 separately, corrupting that Unicode codepoint.

Comment: @RemyLebeau thanks for that excellent explanation. Admittedly I was lazy, and the code change (as you see) actually is minor.